# What is known about evil primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, binary

An **[evil number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_number)** is a positive integer $n$ that has an even number of $1$s in its binary expansion. Many theorems exist about evil numbers, the most known ones are probably those that involve the Thue-Morse sequence.

However, I find no information about prime numbers having an even number of $1$s in their binary expansion. What is known about such numbers?

While it is obvious that the asymptotic density of evil numbers is $1/2$, is there an equivalent result/conjecture concerning evil primes?

Finally, is there anything known about the sum of the reciprocals of evil primes? (For evil numbers see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143799/sum-of-reciprocal-of-evil-odious-numbers).)

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44561/odd-bit-primes-ratio

Comment: Note the OP asked a similar question about $4$ hours later at [Sum of reciprocal of evil/odious numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143799/sum-of-reciprocal-of-evil-odious-numbers).

Comment: On another note: how can evil be a positive?

Comment: @usiro I don't understand the question

Comment: It is just odd how they called these numbers with this adjective, but coming back to to main question, there is an interesting pattern based on a difference between consecutive terms - I would start with that...

Comment: @usiro Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Klangen I can, providing you've done more research on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very similar [Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44561/odd-bit-primes-ratio), in which it was shown that the ratio of odd-bit primes against even-bit primes approaches $1/2$. In fact, the rigourous proof can be found in

C. Mauduit and J. Rivat, *Sur un problème de Gelfond: la somme des chiffres des nombres premiers*, Ann. Math.