# Sum of reciprocal of evil/odious numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

A positive integer $n$ is said to be **evil** if the sum of $1$s in its binary expansion is even, **odious** otherwise. Is anything known about the sum of reciprocals of evil numbers?

Comment: You asked a very similar question about $4$ hours earlier at [What is known about evil primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143620/what-is-known-about-evil-primes). A comment by Barry Cipra gave a link to MO [Odd-bit primes ratio](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44561/odd-bit-primes-ratio) which was useful there, & could also be useful here for anybody reading this question. I believe the general policy on this site is you should try to avoid asking such similar questions or, at the least, provide a link if you do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $n$, one of $2n$ and $2n+1$ is evil and the other is odious.
So you can get upper and lower bounds of the sum of reciprocals of the evil numbers up to $N$ in terms of the sums of reciprocals of the even and odd numbers up to $N$, for which good asymptotics are known.